# What is the upper bound for Lightspeed?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics

Followup to my [lower bound light speed](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/147546/what-is-the-lower-bound-for-lightspeed) question. I was told on the Sandbox to split the lower and upper bound for light speed in different Questions. Yes they are similar but it is possible that different formulas bind the light speed to a low bound than to an upper bound.

I am investigating the possibility of modifying the speed of light in my world.  Assuming that the speed of light in a vacuum can (and in my world, is) modified, what upper bound exists that would permit humanity to exist?

**I want to know how high light speed could get while still allowing for humans to live.**

Comment: Given L.Dutch's answer and my comment on your lower-bound question, this question will probably go the way of the dodo.

Comment: I would remove this question, indeed. It's basically a duplicate of your other one

Comment: @L.Dutch I was told in the Sandbox to split my Question up because otherwise it would be to broad.

Comment: There's no reason to think humans (or even the universe as we know it) would even exist if light speed wasn't exactly what it is.

Comment: @Soan, what didn't get caught in the Sandbox is that they're the same question.  There isn't an upper or lower bound to light speed.  There's just one speed: *c.*

Comment: @JBH I know that there is only one speed for light in a vacuum, but I wanted to know how big the changes to light speed could be when Human life is still possible.

Comment: So, you know the upper bound, the speed in a vacuum.  The speed of light does change in a *medium.*  For example, the speed of light in pure water is [225,000 kps](https://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/java/speedoflight/index.html) and even slower in other materials.  Are you asking what the speed of light would be in the least breathable atmosphere that humans can tolerate?  It'll obviously be faster than the speed in water.  If so, I'd still advocate this question be deleted and the other question clarified.  (@L.Dutch, would you agree?)

Comment: @JBH No I am asking whether changing the speed of light in a vacuum would still allow Humans to survive and if that's the case what the limit for changing said speed would be.

Comment: The question looks like a duplicate as a consequence of the answer. Question-wise it makes sense to separate the two cases.

Comment: See [my answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/147561/29552) at the sister question about a lower bound. A different $c$ means different $\varepsilon_0$ or a different $\mu_0$ or both, which means that all electromagnetic phenomena have different strength, which means that all chemistry is different. Different chemistry entails no humans. Life might be possible, intelligent life might be possible, but there will be *no humans*.

Comment: OK, I'm finally getting it.  *If* we modify the speed of light, within what range could human life exist?  OK.  thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'm one of many users here who comment on new questions to ask the poster to focus on just one question and leave others for later.  But here's a great example of when two separate questions are really one.  It's okay to ask "what are the upper and lower bounds for lightspeed?"  Looking at the Sandbox, yes you are right someone did suggest separating them.  But I think that person was mistaken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the lower bound for lightspeed?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/147546/what-is-the-lower-bound-for-lightspeed)

Comment: Like your question about the lower bound, this does not appear to be about worldbuilding as defined in the [help]. VTC:OT:NAW

Comment: @Soan What makes you think anyone answering questions on WB is capable of explaining why the fine fine-structure constant dictates life as we know it? I mean many, given enough time and research, could come up with something... but I think you would better off taking 6 years of physics from Timothy Berners-Lee  and even then I doubt you (or anyone for that matter) would truly understand.

Answer (score 1):

The [fine-structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) is the one controlling most of the properties allowing life as we know to exist.

It can be expressed as $\alpha=\cfrac{ k_e\cdot e^2}{\hbar\cdot c}$, where

- $k_e$ is the Coulomb constant
- $e$ is the elementary charge
- $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum
- $\hbar$ is Planck constant

As you see, if you change $c$ you change $\alpha$, and that would make life impossible.

> The anthropic principle is a controversial argument of why the fine-structure constant has the value it does: stable matter, and therefore life and intelligent beings, could not exist if its value were much different. For instance, were α to change by 4%, stellar fusion would not produce carbon, so that carbon-based life would be impossible. If α were greater than 0.1, stellar fusion would be impossible, and no place in the universe would be warm enough for life as we know it.

Therefore

> What would be the lower bound for light speed which still allows Human live?

Exactly what it is: $c$

Comment: Seriously y’all, don’t mess with the fundamental constants.

Comment: @JoeBloggs ...without reading the manual first.

Comment: Isn't the traditional symbol for the Planck constant $\hbar$ (`\hbar`)?

Comment: @aCVn, yes, but I didn't know the mathjax code to write it -.-''

Comment: It's `\hbar`. (filler)

Comment: Useful link for next time: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/53424) and, for those times when you know a symbol but not the LaTeX for it, [Detexify2](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) (that's also mentioned in one of the answers to the earlier-linked Meta question).

Comment: I don't think your conclusion in this answer or in [the related answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/147550/53612) follow the setup you've provided. You are given "c is one parameter that influences α" and "if α changes even by a small amount, life is impossible" and then conclude that "if c changes by a small amount, life is impossible". There are other constants in your function that the OP could modify in parallel or opposition to "c" and still have the same "α". You should elaborate on why this strategy would not work to make life possible with a different "c".

Comment: @DavidCoffron, OP is asking about changing, c, not about changing c and other constants.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone here has sufficient expertise to answer your question definitively -- and I have certainly not noticed anything in the professional literature which answers your question.  But I think I can approach it with an analogy:

Some scientists have looked at the possibilities of a universe without the weak force (the weak force is responsible for radioactivity and has a major impact on how stars produce energy.  The conclusion is that such a universe could evolve stars and planets and thus life.

Here's a link to one such paper: [Universes without the Weak Force: Astrophysical Processes with Stable Neutrons](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.06081.pdf?) and here's another: [Nuclear Processes in Other Universes: Varying the Strength of the Weak Force](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.05128.pdf?).

My strong guess is that if a life-bearing universe without the weak force is possible, one with a somewhat larger speed of light ought to be, also.  But going much deeps requires detailed analysis.